# Arduino SD Card saved File is not plain Text

Tags: arduino, binary, sd-card, ubuntu-16.04, iconv

for a test i use the SD Card sample ReadWrite from the Arduino IDE.
The Arduino self can write and read the data, but when i mount die SD Card on Ubuntu 16.04 i see the File but the content is only tangled signs.
file -i tell me "application/octet-stream; charset=binary".
The problem can be solved in two ways.
The Arduino write the file as plain txt.
Or i can convert the file to plain txt.
I try iconf but i can't find the right "from code", binary is not the right from code.

Has someone a solution?

regards ThomasD

Comment: Hello, i have new infos i use "SD.open", "print" and "close" command. I think the file is not closed properly, because If I open a new file, The old one is text-readable. File -i output is: "text/plain; charset=binary".

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a charset, if you write a new file to a (fat32) SD card using arduino. AFAIK, there's a `iocharset` option when mounting such a SD card on linux ?

What does

```
iconv -f ASCII <your file>
```

show on your linux ?